# push Async data to an array react

Tags: reactjs

This is my code:

```
           if (this.state.counter===questions.length-1)
         {
            for(let i = 0 ; i < this.state.user_answer.length; i++){
              if(this.state.user_answer[i]===key[i]){
                //problem starts here
                this.setState(prevState => {return {score: prevState.score + 1}},()=>{
                  //gives me correct data for score
                  console.log("score1:",this.state.score);
                })
                }
            }
            //gives me score:0 (always)
            console.log("score2:",this.state.score);
            //i want to add correct data to my array but it adds number 0
            this.state.top_score.push([this.state.score])
         }
```

I want the data I made in `setState` push in the `top_score` array.

What should I do?

Comment: Why not doing `this.state.top_score.push(this.state.score)` where you are getting right answer for `score`?

Comment: how? i tried  `score: prevState.score + 1; this.state.top_score.push(this.state.score)` 
 and i got error.

Comment: the way I mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to setState outside the for:

```
if (this.state.counter===questions.length-1)
     {
        let score = this.state.score;
        for(let i = 0 ; i < this.state.user_answer.length; i++){
          if(this.state.user_answer[i]===key[i]){

            //problem starts here
           score += 1;                
            }
        }

        console.log("score2:",score);

       this.setState({score});

        //i want to add correct data to my array but it adds number 0
        this.state.top_score.push([score])
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, try to destruct your state for better use of your state and clean code and you have to update your array property in your state like so :

```
let {top_score , score , counter , user_answer} = this.state;

if (counter===questions.length-1)
     {
        let tempScore = score;
        for(let i = 0 ; i < user_answer.length; i++){
          if(user_answer[i]===key[i]){
           score += 1;                
            }
        }

        console.log("score2:",tempScore);
       let tempArr = [...top_score];
       tempArr.push(tempScore)
       this.setState({score : tempScore , top_score : tempArr});
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want `score` to be pushed in `top_score` array.

Solution:

```
     if (this.state.counter===questions.length-1)
     {
        for(let i = 0 ; i < this.state.user_answer.length; i++){
          if(this.state.user_answer[i]===key[i]){

            //problem starts here
            this.setState(prevState => {{score: prevState.score + 1}}, ()=>{

              //gives me correct data for score
              console.log("score1:",this.state.score);
              this.setState({top_score: [...this.state.top_score, this.state.score]})
            })
            }
        }

     }
```

Tip: You never **return** in react world.

**Update in Code**

**Previous:**

`this.state.top_score.push(this.state.score) // this would work but mutates state directly which is discouraged in React`

**Current:**

`this.setState({top_score: [...this.state.top_score, this.state.score]}) //without mutation of state`

Comment: I also tried your solution, but i got error: `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," `

Comment: Thats because } in my code was not on right place. Updated my code. :)

Answer (score 0):

Very well, you've found one of the most difficult concepts to understand in javascript: the fact that it is asynchronous. There is a lot to be said about this topic, but the main key to understand is that code is not necessarily executed from top to bottom (as in other languages, such as `Python`). Instead, the javascript engine doesn't wait for some blocks of code to finish execution (such as your `for` loop) before it runs other statements coming next. So in your case, the block:

```js
//gives me score:0 (always)
console.log("score2:",this.state.score);

//i want to add correct data to my array but it adds number 0
this.state.top_score.push([this.state.score])
```

can get executed before the `for` loop above finishes (depending how long this takes). What this means in practice is that, the call to `setState` is happening after you try to access the value of `score`, and as it hasn't been updated yet, it's still `0`. Another key aspect that I see in your code is an anti-pattern of modifying directly `state`. In React you shouldn't do this, and instead use `this.setState` method, which is optimized for updating `state`. You could also make use of a more functional approach to javascript by using [array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and ES6 features to make your code cleaner.

My suggestion for your code would be:

```js
if (this.state.counter === questions.length-1){
    const { userAnswer } = this.state;

    // This will go over each element of the array `userAnswer`
    userAnswer.forEach((answer, i) => {
        if(answer === key[i]) {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                score: prevState.score + 1,
                // Here you are making use of array spread syntax https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
                topScore: [...prevState.topScore, prevState.score + 1]
            }))
        }
     })
}
```